# Quick Vertical Tangent Line Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"The position of a car moving along a flat surface at time $t$ is modeled by $(x(t), y(t))$ with velocity vector $v(t)=<3+6\sin(3t), 1+e^{2t}>$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2$. Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are measured in feet, and $t$ is measured in seconds. At time $t=0$, the car is at position $(0,0)$. At what time $t$, for $0≤t≤2$, is the line tangent to the path of the car parallel to the $y$-axis?"

Albeit this question is a bit similar to the last one I asked, I was given the same prompt with a different ending. This ending is also a bit confusing to me, I understand that the vertical tangent line in an equation can be found by setting the denominator of a fraction to $0$, but I'm confused about how I might go about doing that here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I find your use of inequality symbols  a little confusing, eg when describing the velocity. Do you think you could edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when the tangent is vertical
$$v_x(t)=3+6\sin(3t)=0$$
which yields $t = \frac{7}{18}\pi,\>\frac{11}{18}\pi$.